# Can't mount my external USB hard drive to my Ubuntu 14.04 guest in Virtualbox

Tags: usb, mount, virtualbox

I have a feeling it may have something to do with what type of USB i'm using.  If i plug in a USB 2.0 device(like my flash drive), it will be recognized.  But if I plug in a USB 3.0 device, it will no be recognized.  Can anyone help me with this issue? Thx in advance.

Comment: i suggest you ask on the virtual box forums as this is not reaay ubuntu related

Answer (score 1):

At present VirtualBox 4.3. does not support USB 3.0. As a workaround you may succed in connecting your device to a USB 2.0 port or a USB 2.0 hub.

According to [VirtualBox ticket #8873](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8873#comment:35) we may try to attach a USB 3.0 hard drive as a raw disk to the guest OS for a faster transfer speed but this may only work in some cases.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Thx!